# Why are my NPCs on Terraria Mobile not moving back into my tree home?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I killed all my NPCs (including the Goblin Tinkerer), but after a while I have not gotten any messages saying "(NPC Name) would like to settle down."

The only NPCs that move back into my tree home are:

- Nurse
- Arms Dealer
- Guide
- Merchant

  Nobody else moves back in. Please help! It's been one day now!

Answer (score 1):

Just get everyone else to move in, and then he should eventually move in.